# Comparison of bigrams between lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I've got 2 lists with bigrams in them. E.g:

```
List1 = [('bribe charge'), ('brilliant loss'),  ('brisk isolated'), ('brutal divorce')]
List2 = [['bribe', 'charge'], ['a', 'baby'], ['a', 'shoe'], ['a', 'brisk'], ['the', 'goat']]
```

So I want to check and compare the 2 lists and check for the bigrams that are the same in both lists and output it. 
So the desired output should be : `"bribe charge."`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Your List1 is just a list of two word strings, not like List2 that is a list of lists. Were you intending ('bribe charge' , ) or ('bribe', 'charge') ???

Comment: I was intending ('bribe charge' , )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to make both lists the same types and then you can convert them to sets and do an intersect.

```
List2 = {' '.join(x) for x in List2}
isct = set(List1) & List2
```

Comment: How would i go about doing this?